# How do I enable IPv6 support in LWP?

Tags: perl, ipv6, lwp

The following code ...

```
my $user_agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $request = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
my $response = $user_agent->request($request);
if ($response->is_success) {
    print "OK\n";
} else {
    die($response->status_line);
}
```

.. will fail with ..

```
500 Can't connect to <hostname> (Bad hostname '<hostname>')
```

.. if the hostname in $url is an IPv6 only address (that is: presence of an `AAAA` record, but no `A` record).

My questions are:

- How do I enable IPv6 support in LWP?
- How do I configure LWP's settings for "prefer-IPv4-over-IPv6" (`A` vs. `AAAA`) / "prefer-IPv6-over-IPv4" (`AAAA` vs. `A`)?

Comment: Did you mention your OS? I couldn't spot it. Not 100% sure but it might be relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you just need to use [Net::INET6Glue::INET_is_INET6](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::INET6Glue::INET_is_INET6).  To quote its example:

```
 use Net::INET6Glue::INET_is_INET6;
 use LWP::Simple;
 print get( 'http://[::1]:80' );
 print get( 'http://ipv6.google.com' );
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'll have to change the module to use the IPV6 net module. By default it does not have this enabled: http://eintr.blogspot.com/2009/03/bad-state-of-ipv6-in-perl.html. I don't believe there is something as simple as "prefer-ipv6"

Answer (score 1):

Debian Wheezy (perl 5.14)

**Work nice:**

```
use LWP::Simple;
print get( 'http://ip6-localhost:80' );
```

**Not working** (1)

```
use LWP::Simple;
print get( 'http://[::1]:80' );
```

**Not working** (2) [Return: **Bad hostname**]

```
use LWP::Simple;
$ua = new LWP::UserAgent();
my $req = new HTTP::Request("GET", "http://[::1]/");
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

**Not working** (3) [Return: **Connection refused**]

```
use Net::INET6Glue::INET_is_INET6;
use LWP::Simple;
$ua = new LWP::UserAgent();
my $req = new HTTP::Request("GET", "http://[::1]/");
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

Soo, if you don't need IPv6 address in http request, it's fine. :(